# Two similar apps share a DB needs to add migration on one app based on requirement and should run from other app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have two similar rails app and use a common DB and based on the requirement we have to add migration on both app.
Now I What I want

```
 -  Add a migration on app1
 -  run rake db:migrate one app2
```

It must run migration present on app1 and vice versa 
is it possible?

In simple any migration added on any app should be update DB when run rake db:migrate on other app.

I think we can do by rails engine but not sure how, any suggestion?

Comment: I do not want to copy the same migration on each app

Comment: Can you explain why you need to run a migration on app2? It's a bad idea having two apps with migrations on the same DB. You'll inevitably have conflicts. Better to keep all in one db.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a common database, or a common schema?

If it's actually a shared database then you only need to run the migrate once, and should only store migrates in one of the two applications. Changes made to the database via one application will immediately affect the other application.

Comment: it is common database

Comment: Then once you migrate in db1, it will reflect in db2

Comment: No I have common db, once a migration added on app1 and run rake db:migrate on app2 it should reflect in DB, it seems silly question but in my case I need this

Comment: Why isn't your migrate in app2, or why don't you run migrate on app1? The only way to get migrates from one app to be run in the other would be to symlink the migrate directory (or similar approach of sharing the actual file).

Answer (score 0):

In your another app, run this rake task:

```
bundle exec rake db:schema:dump
```

These will generate a schema from the database, no need for migration copied.But without app1, app2 may not work properly.